# Full width image in separated row on wordpress (Ref attacted)

Tags: wordpress, image, layout, responsive

He everyone,
simple question for everone.
I am trying to build this style but i am very new in WordPress and cant figure it out myself.
See the link below:
https://blind.com/what-we-do/

I like the part "Strategy, Branding, Digital, Motion" with the test one side and image the other side.
I would like to recreate this exact style with the Responsiveness included.

Thank you for your help.
Alexandre

Answer (score 0):

Since you've mentioned that you're using Siteorigin's page builder, I've decided to do a short video of how I would arrange the elements on the builder to achieve the results you're after.

here's my screencast: http://somup.com/cFit60VLyy

Now there are few flaws with siteorigin's pagebuilder - there is no inbuilt column equalizer for rows unlike other page builders like WPbakery and elementor. So you will have to use a plugin or write your own CSS. If you want to go the plugin way, install the [Equal height columns](https://wordpress.org/plugins/equal-height-columns/) plugin

And then you can add a class to any column you want to have equal width on left and right. You can see in my video that I've used the "equal" class under the attributes of the cells.

Depending on the theme you're using, you might need to write some CSS for margins and paddings. I'm sure its quite straight forward. You can do this in 10 mins straight.

Good luck.

Comment: Hey,
Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: I cannot get it perfectly the same though. Especially the responsiveness nature of those images. 
Do you have any advice for that?

Comment: The responsive version of your reference website is quite simple. I see that the horizontal columns just stack up as vertical columns on mobile and ipad. Which builder are you using?

Comment: Hi Ash, Im just using the SiteOrigin stuff. But i still cannot get the the image to fit the entire space. I dont want there to be any white space, the image must cover everything.

Comment: I have edited the answer and added a video which should help you. Please check that and you should be able to make things happen. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the vid ash. could you tell me how to css instead of using a plugin